# Cout char from different codepage than system uses

Tags: c++, codepages

I need to put out a single char, but codepage my system using doesn't have that symbol (i.e. spanish exclamation point "¡"). 
Trying

```
char excl = 173; 
cout.put(excl);
```

but it types another symbol.

Comment: On Windows I suppose?

Comment: @BaummitAugen Yes it's Windows OS. Im interested is there a way to do so in Visual Studio for example. Without changing smth in OS

Comment: That should be what you are looking I think.

Comment: Hm, not quite apparently. I'll leave this for someone who knows Windows. Good luck.

Comment: What's the language settings of your OS?

Comment: It's certainly possible to change the codepage of the console. It's worth noting this character is in Windows-1252.

Comment: in 1252 the character has a value of 161

Answer (score 3):

If the settings of the operating system are not configured to the approriate codepage you first have to set the locale:

```
setlocale( LC_ALL, "esp" );
```

This sets your locale to Spanish_Spain.1252 ([Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252))
Then the character is under the value 161

```
char excl = 161;
std::cout.put( excl );
```

---

[std::setlocale](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/setlocale)

> The setlocale function installs the specified system locale or its portion as the new C locale. The modifications remain in effect and influences the execution of all locale-sensitive C library functions until the next call to setlocale.

Explaination of constants:

> - LC_ALL : selects the entire C locale
> - LC_COLLATE : selects the collation category of the C locale
> - LC_CTYPE : selects the character classification category of the C locale
> - LC_MONETARY : selects the monetary formatting category of the C locale
> - LC_NUMERIC : selects the numeric formatting category of the C locale
> - LC_TIME : selects the time formatting category of the C locale

Comment: It seems to have switched to 1252, but now puts out "?" instead of similar symbols.

Comment: Where are you seeing the "?" character? (console app, gui, ...). Please explain your project.

Comment: Its in Visual Studio

Comment: I dont understand what "Visual Studio" means to You.

Comment: I see results in console of Visual Studio (or also called VC++ if I understand right)

Comment: What language settings is in your WIndows?

Comment: You can check what locale is set with: ```std::cout << setlocale( LC_CTYPE, "esp" ) << '\n';```

Comment: Language settings are Russian. It seemed to put out symbols in 866 code page. Maybe I should change something in compiler?

Comment: Maybe this will help (Win10): Got to Windows Settings -> Time & language -> Region and language -> Languages -> Add a language -> Spanish

Comment: To display the characters correctly, you need to have the appropriate codepages and supporting fonts installed. Did you try to change the font of your console you eg. Arial?

Answer (score 0):

What finally worked was

```
SetConsoleCP(1252);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1252);
```

Probably because I reinstalled VC++ and chose only English language pack during installation.